# Google App Engine Datastore multi-field key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable ="false")
public class Foo implements IsSerializable {

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private Long revision;

    @Persistent
    private String information;
}
```

The problem is this object keeps overwriting itself when persisted, not creating a new 'record' with the next revision.
In a traditional [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) it'd be a two-column primary key.

How do I accomplish this with [Google App Engine Datastore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Differences_between_SQL_and_GQL)?

Comment: why the single white-space edit?

Comment: It removed the horizontal slider on the code :)

Comment: the slider is still there in my maximized firefox window, on a 1600x1200 screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best way to solve it.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,detachable = "false")
public class Foo implements IsSerializable {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Long _internalId;

  @Persistent
  private Long id;

  @Persistent
  private Long revision;

  @Persistent
  private String information;
}
```

where id and revision are treated as the primary key in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and write a new record for each update if you want to keep a revision history. The id uniquely identifies the record - the Datastore has no way of knowing that you consider the revision to be part of the id too.